# How should I specify command-line arguments for atd?

Tags: 11.04, command-line, configuration, services

The [manual for atd](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/en/man8/atd.8.html) describes the command-line option:

> **-b** Specify the minimum interval in seconds between the start of two
>   batch jobs (60 default).

How can I permanently set this option so that, for example, jobs queued by `batch` are allowed to run within 10 seconds of each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ubuntu 11.04 atd is started in `/etc/init/atd.conf`. Modify the line

```
exec atd
```

to use the command-line options you want.

In older version of Ubuntu atd be be started in something like `/etc/init.d/atd` using normal shell syntax. If you have such a version and need help editing please provide that file.